# Show that if the numbers $\sqrt{a^2+b+c+1}$, $\sqrt{b^2+c+a+1}$ and $\sqrt{c^2+a+b+1 }$ are rational, then $a = b = c$

Tags: radicals, rational-numbers, square-numbers

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be nonzero natural numbers.  Show that if the numbers $\sqrt{a^2+b+c+1}$, $\sqrt{b^2+c+a+1}$ and $\sqrt{c^2+a+b+1  }$ are rational, then $a = b = c$.

*My ideas*

For those numebrs to be rational the numbers in the radical must be perfect squares.

I wrote them as some petfect squares.

> $a^2+b+c+1=x^2$

> $b^2+c+a+1=y^2$

> $c^2+b+a+1=z^2$

Atfer summing them up

$a^2+b^2+c^2+2a+2b+2c+3=(a+1)^2+(b+1)^2+(c+1)^2$

Supposing that $a=b=c$ we arrive at the conclusion that we must show that ${a+1}^2=x^2$ and so on.

The form we wrote the numbers as is really close to what we must show. Hope one of can help me! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear that the numbers in the radical must be perfect squares，you could choose the largest number of $a,b,c$, WLOG, assume $a \ge b \ge c$.

Notice that $$a^2 \lt a^2+b+c+1 \le (a+1)^2$$
you only need to find when the equality holds.

Comment: I have a question. Why can we assume the inequality $a \ge b \ge c$?

Comment: I have a question. Why can we assume the inequality a≥b≥c
?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Assume, WLOG, $a\geq b\geq c$ and consider the implications of $a^2+b+c+1$ being a perfect square.

Comment: This answer does not appear to offer any additional insight other than what the OP has in their question.

Comment: @Doug Huh?  I don't sum over the three equations instead concentrating on only one.  Anyway, the other answers now cover the same approach.